# Setting default image title based on post title

Tags: wordpress, filter

I would like to create a filter which will by default add post title as all image titles in wordpress during file upload. I know that for this purpose i can use:

wp_insert_attachement_data

I've wrote something like that:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_attachment_data', 'wpq_insert_attachment_data', 10, 2 );

function wpq_insert_attachment_data( $data, $postarr ) {

$append = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );

// Append to the image caption field: 
if( false == stripos( $data['post_excerpt'], $append ) ) {
$data['post_excerpt'] .= $append; 
}

// Append to the image description field: 
if( false == stripos( $data['post_content'], $append ) ) {
$data['post_content'] .= $append; 
}

return $data;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code, it is replacing default image title with post title. I have tried it and it is working.

```
 function wpq_insert_attachment_data($data, $postarr){

      $posttitle = get_the_title( $postarr['post_parent'] );
      $data['post_title'] = $posttitle;
      $data['post_name'] = $posttitle;    
      return $data;
        }
add_filter( 'wp_insert_attachment_data', 'wpq_insert_attachment_data', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: @Pawel Skaba: you wel come :)